# Bootstrap Popover Button Does Not Display in IE 8

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, freemarker, twitter-bootstrap-2

There are countless issues with Bootstrap (in my case, 2.3.1) components utilized in older versions of IE. My issue has a whole bunch of other potential wrenches that could be the culprit in the app environment: jQuery + Bootstrap known conflicts, Java using Spring framework, Freemarker templates, &c., &c.

But my issue is simply trying to get one button on a Bootstrap popover to display in IE, and currently it will not, though there are no issues in Chrome, Firefox, &c. (I know, shocking, right?). I have a Freemarker template calling data-content to populate a popover on a link, a popover with two `<a>` tags with a class of `btn`:

```
<li class="popout document-toc" id="document-toc">
  <a class="reader-sprite toc pop-right" href="#" title="Table of Contents &amp; Notes" 
  data-content="<a href='#' class='btn btn-inverse contents'>
  <@spring.message "reader.actionbar.toc.contents"/></a>
  <a href='#' class='btn btn-inverse notes'>
  <@spring.message "reader.actionbar.toc.notes"/></a>
  <div class='content-pane'><h1 class='gradient'>&nbsp;
  <#--<@spring.message "reader.actionbar.toc.label"/>--></h1>
  <p class='no-toc'><@spring.message "reader.actionbar.toc.missing"/></p></div>
  <div class='notes-pane hidden'><h1 class='gradient'>&nbsp;
  <#--<@spring.message "reader.actionbar.toc.notes.label"/>--></h1></div>"></a>
</li>
```

The issue is that the `content` button will display but the `notes` button will not. Both have a display of `inline-block`, there is now much more width than is necessary for the `notes` button to fit, but nothing I do seems to be able to get it to display. I suspect the issue is not in Spring or Freemarker, esp. given that this is pretty basic mark-up, and also given the amount of research I've been doing on both -- but at this point, I really don't know what the issue is. I welcome any recommendations people might have for a solution and/or further investigation. Thanks for your attention.

UPDATE: One notable aspect I didn't mention is that this missing button comes up fine in IE 8 Compatibility View. Probably the best answer to this issue is "don't use IE 8," but our major corporate clients will undoubtedly disagree. :/

Comment: You should really update to v2.3.2. BTW, you're aware v2 is dead, right?

Comment: Completely out of my hands. And yes, Bootstrap 3.x would be even more preferable.

Answer (score 0):

hard to debug with only partial HTML but I would try with:

1.) is HTML (and CSS) valid (or at least close to valid)?

2.)  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />`

3.) IE COMPATIBILITY VIEW AND X-UA-COMPATIBLE

2. and 3. resources can be found on MSDN and/or Google (sorry, can't publish direct links due to rep')...